# add incremental numbering suffix to file save macro/vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that is repeating an export to pdf and save process, but the loop just keeps overwriting the same file with each save and I want it to add new a new file each time. I figure I need to have something in the code to add an incremental number suffix to the file name but am struggling to figure out now to embed that into the existing loop process. Any help on how to complete that is much appreciated! Here is my current macro:

```
    Sub Print_Card()
    '
    ' Print_Card Macro
    '
    Let x = 0
    Do While x < 10
    
    Calculate
    
    Dim loc As String
    loc = "C:\Folder\FileName.pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=loc, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        From:=1, To:=2
    
    x = x + 1
    
    Loop
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Could use `loc = "C:\Folder\Filename" & x+1 & ".pdf"`. I'm not familiar with `Let x = 0` in a normal Sub however, normal VBA syntax would be something like `Dim x As Long : x = 0` (also not sure why you have Calculate there unless it's for a time update in a cell?)

Comment: thank you @Notus_Panda! adding the "&  x+1 &" between the file name and extension did the trick! and yes...the calculate is in there to process an update between each file export/save. appreciate the quick feedback and help!

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding! :)

Comment: `adding the "& x+1 &" between the file name and extension` will create 10 exactly same pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

- looking for the latest copy first, eg. File_Name2.pdf
- Next run will create a file named File_Name3.pdf

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Print_Card()
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim i As Long
    Const BASE_DIR = "C:\Folder\"
    Const FILE_NAME = "File_Name"
    Const FILE_EXT = ".pdf"
    Const MAX_INDEX = 10
    ' Const BASE_DIR = "D:\TEMP\" ' for testing
    ' looking for the latest copy
    For i = MAX_INDEX To 1 Step -1
        sFile = Dir(BASE_DIR & FILE_NAME & i & FILE_EXT)
        If Len(sFile) > 0 Then
            sFile = BASE_DIR & FILE_NAME & i + 1 & FILE_EXT
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ' no matching
    If Len(sFile) = 0 Then
        sFile = BASE_DIR & FILE_NAME & "1" & FILE_EXT
    End If
    Calculate
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FILE_NAME:=sFile, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, From:=1, to:=2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library, you could check if the file existed in a loop and edit the name until it was no longer detected.  I prefer this method because the File System Object's methods tell you exactly what they're doing.  For example, there's not much confusion about what `FSO.FileExists` is going to do.

```
Sub Print_Card()
    
    ' Microsoft Scripting Runtime required
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.fileSystemObject
    
    ' Splitting the path and the extension as we may need to edit
    Dim loc As String, extension As String, fullPath As String
    loc = "C:\Folder\FileName"
    extension = ".pdf"
    fullPath = loc & extension

    Dim number As Long
    number = 1
    
    ' Does the file exist?  If so, do the steps in the block below
    Do While FSO.FileExists(fullPath)
    
        ' Remove previous number
        extension = Replace(extension, number, "")
        
        ' Add new number
        extension = Str(number) & extension
        
        ' Update fullPath
        fullPath = loc & extension
        
        ' Iterate the number
        number = number + 1
    
    Loop
    
    ' Once the code reaches here, the file path is unique
    ' Add whatever code you want
    
End Sub
```