# how can i save file in excel as pdf with same name at same place automatically

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am using micro to save my bills copy as pdf from excel but every time i run micro previously saved file rplace by new one. any solution to put number after file name automatically?

i try vba in excel but lase save file replace by new one

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77565716/add-incremental-numbering-suffix-to-file-save-macro-vba